# Unable to download Cynogenmod from its official site

Tags: android, android-studio, custom-rom

I am trying to download Cynogenmod v13 for Moto G1 mobile(Falcon) from the official website https://download.cyanogenmod.org/ but none of the links on that page are working, I keep on getting "The site cannot be reached error.".

Could you please help me get Cynogenmod V13 for Moto G1 device?

Comment: Since this question isn't directly related to programming, http://android.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41896258/5734097), Cyanogenmod is dead...

But you can download the Cyanogenmod from this mirror:
https://vegazs.github.io/MirrorCyanogenMod/falcon.html

Answer (score -1):

CM is dead... rumored internal conflict and a dropped deal with 1+ meant the money hose dried up. they began cutting services Dec. 31 and continue to do so. Source code is still available, but not much else is known right now. [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/cyanogenmod-is-dead-and-its-successor-is-lineage-os-1790554964)

**Edit** 
Actually LineageOS (successor) just got some of it's sites partially working and has at least one build for most phones in the lineup. it's still a bit of a mess, but [here's](https://download.lineageos.org/) the download portal.